# Can not select multiple LDAP servers with authconfig bug report

Tags: openldap, centos7, bugzilla, master-slave

There is this bug report "Can not select multiple LDAP servers with authconfig" 
Red Hat Bugzilla – Bug 1142830; https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1142830

which is suppose to be solved on version authconfig-6.2.8-9.el7.

I am using authconfig version: 6.2.8-10.el7.x86_64 which is higher.

This version should have the fix in it. But I still have this problem where only the first ldap server I declare becomes the server and if I switch it off the consumer does not kick in unless it is declared first.

```
authconfig --ldapserver=ldaps://provider.example.com,ldaps://consumer.example.com --update
```

. I am using centos 7, and this is Red hat, but should have the fixe. Anyone has any thoughts or comments on this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`authconfig` is only a tool to change the configuration of other software, including LDAP integration tools such as `nslcd`, `sssd`, etc.

The bug you linked to is about being unable to specify multiple LDAP servers on the `authconfig` command line, however it sounds like the problem you're experiencing is that the software *configured* by `authconfig` with multiple servers is not failing over correctly when one of the servers fails.

It's not clear what LDAP integration tool you're using but I'd suggest turning your attention to that rather than `authconfig`.